# Duplicating objects in a list such that they repeat

Tags: python, pandas

How do I duplicate elements in a lists such that they repeat?

```html
Input: ListA = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Output: ListA = [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9]
```

Comment: Iterate over the list items and append each item twice to a new list.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You've used the javascript formatter and tagged your question with pandas. Neither has anything to do with your question. Show what you have tried so far (code) and be specific about which part is giving you trouble. Read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Most straight-forward way: `[x for x in input_list for _ in range(n)]` where `n` is the number of times you want something to repeat, (in this case, `n == 2`)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `np.repeat()`

```
ListA = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
ListA = np.repeat([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 2)
ListA
```

**Output**

```
array([1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the easiest way with the sorted list given is:

```py
ListA = sorted(ListA + ListA)
```

... but this does assume that the original ListA was sorted. Otherwise you can do it in a procedural fashion:

```py
ListAcopy = []
for el in ListA:
    ListAcopy.extend([el,el])
ListA = ListAcopy
```

or through a two-layer zip list comprehension

```py
ListA = [item for pair in zip(ListA,ListA) for item in pair]
```